# In R Markdown using R code chunks, can two images be placed on one the same line with one aligned left and one aligned right?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm creating a pdf using R Markdown with a header that has two logos, one aligned left and one right.  Because I'm using R code chunks to resize the images, the result has the second in a new line.  Is it possible to have two images on the same line but with different alignment?

This is the current code, resulting in images on separate lines:

````
---
title: ''
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r logo, echo=FALSE,out.width="200px",out.height="200px",fig.align='left'}
knitr::include_graphics("pic1.jpg")
```
```{r logo2, echo=FALSE, out.width="200px",out.height="200px",fig.align='right'}
knitr::include_graphics("pic2.jpg")
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Here I've assumed we're laying out two general images, rather than plots. If your images are actually plots you've created, then you can lay them out as a single image for display using `gridExtra::grid.arrange` for grid graphics or `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` for base graphics and thereby avoid the complications of laying out two separate images.

I'm not sure if there's a "natural" way to left justify the left-hand image and right-justify the right-hand image. As a hack, you could add a blank "spacer" image to separate the two "real" images and set the widths of each image to match paper-width minus 2*margin-width.

Here's an example where the paper is assumed to be 8.5" wide and the right and left margins are each 1":

````
---
output: pdf_document
geometry: margin=1in
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)

# Create a blank image to use for spacing
spacer = ggplot() + theme_void() + ggsave("spacer.png")
```

```{r, out.width=c('2.75in','1in','2.75in')}
include_graphics(c("Rplot59.png","spacer.png", "Rplot60.png"))
```
````

And here's what the document looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the same code chunk and do not use align.  Let them use html.

THis has worked for me.

`````
 ````{r echo=FALSE, fig.height=3.0, fig.width=3.0}
 #type your code here
 ggplot(anscombe, aes(x=x1 , y=y1)) + geom_point() 
   +geom_smooth(method="lm") +
   ggtitle("Results for x1 and y1 ")

ggplot(anscombe, aes(x=x2 , y=y2)) + geom_point() +geom_smooth(method="lm") +
   ggtitle("Results for x2 and y2 ")


ggplot(anscombe, aes(x=x3 , y=y3)) + geom_point() +geom_smooth(method="lm") +
   ggtitle("Results for x3 and y3 ")

ggplot(anscombe, aes(x=x4 , y=y4)) + geom_point() +geom_smooth(method="lm") +
   ggtitle("Results for x4 and y4 ")


````
`````

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'let them use html?'  Is that possible if need to output as a pdf document?

Comment: In other words, if you make your images the right size they are going to go next to each other unless you force them not to.  It's not just html.  By putting them in separate chunks you are forcing them not to float next to each other.